# How to replace particular character with leading and following number in string with tcl script?

Tags: string, replace, tcl

I would like to replace a dash (`"-"`) in a string with a dash surrounded by a space on either side (`" - "`), but only when a number is before **and** after the found dash.

For example,

```
-1.5-5.3
```

would turn into

```
-1.5 - 5.3
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried it with different variations of string map and regex. But I don't get it to work. I am quit new with tcl.

Answer (score 0):

```
% puts [regsub -all {(\d)-(\d|-)} "-1-23--42" {\1 - \2}]
-1 - 23 - -42
```